# Check how many times a pattern does not repeat

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am currently working on an Excel spreadsheet where in column B we have the pserial values of each person.

The question is: *how many pserial values in the dataset are incorrect?*

A pserial is an 8-digit value combining the 6-digit hserial value and the persnum value (Person number within household), as a 2-digit value.
for example, for household 1 the pserial is: 10105101 where the last two numbers are the persum and the first 6 are the hserial.
However, a concern has been raised that there may be some bugs in the data, such that some of these
pserial values do not follow this rule and hence are incorrect.

**I can not alter or change any of the data, even if you identify an error**.
This is the spreadsheet, as you can see the data starts in line 11, and there is more data up to row 9291

[image: This is the spreadsheet, as you can see the data starts in line 11, and there is more data up to row 9291]

I am not sure of what code to use but I can use either a macro or a formula here. Feel free to use either of those.

Comment: Do a simple test: =A11=left(c11,6)*1 and then expand for the last 2 digits.

Comment: Yes but this gives me for the first one, i need to count how many of them are incorrect. This only returns a TRUE

Comment: So do it for each row then count the number of true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can check each row if **pserial** column values are well formed. In cell `D2` you can enter the following formula:

```
=IF(C2:C7=1*(A2:A7 & TEXT(B2:B7,"00")), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

**Note**: You can use Conditional Formatting to highlight the errors as follows for the range `D2:D7`:

```
=C2:C7=1*(A2:A7 & TEXT(B2:B7,"00")) = FALSE
```

It assumes the **persnum** column values in **pserial** column is formatted as two digits and the values from **pserial** column are numbers (not text), that is why we multiply by `1` to do the conversation before the comparison. It uses the logic you mentioned in the question for building the **pserial** number from **hserial** and **persnum** columns.

If you want just to calculate the total number of errors, reusing the first formula as follows:

```
=LET(check, IF(C2:C7=1*(A2:A7 & TEXT(B2:B7,"00")), TRUE, FALSE),
 ROWS(FILTER(check, check=FALSE,0)))
```

Comment: I've tried the first formula, used the conditional formatting and all went well, no errors were found. However using the last formula gives me a result of 1. How is possible that they give me different answers? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check you input data, maybe some additional space you enter or something. This calculation is very straightforward. I just tested it with my input data and I am getting `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This formula checks whether the pserial is the same as hersial & persnum as 2digit value, and counts all which are wrong.

```
=SUM(($C$11:$C$20<>NUMBERVALUE($A$11:$A$20&IF(LEN($B$11:$B$20)=1;0&$B$11:$B$20;$B$11:$B$20)))*1)
```

[image]